# Twitter Bootstrap fixed footer on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page that has a fixed footer and header http://magician-bombs-84382.bitballoon.com/

On the footer, I have 4 buttons but the buttons align vertically when the width resizes to less than that of large screens. I am making a page to fit mobile device within this range of media queries

```css
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

The app I'm making will be locked to portrait view, so I'm not thinking of ever accessing the page on large screens.

After looking at the `bootstrap.css` file, I cannot seem to pinpoint the code responsible for arranging the buttons vertically instead of horizontally following the `col-md-3` order available inside the class row.

How can I arrange the buttons horizontally? Removing the `position: absolute` for footer does not seem to solve it.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the footer code on js fiddle ? It would be easy to debug there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.col-xs-3`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), it won't break on extra small screens.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">One</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">One</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">One</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">One</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: If i resize the window and i reach a point where i cannot resize any further, i can only see 3 buttons http://imgur.com/a/4I2xg

Comment: Inspect you code, buttons must be hiding or overflowing due to any other overflowed element, and BTW `320px` narrowest size of mobile phones I guess, and its working on that size.

Comment: Thanks, i found that to be true on my phone, but i will test it on other sizes smaller than mine to see for myself.

Comment: Yep, i confirmed this on smaller screens and it fits perfectly. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine and buttons don't hide also.

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3w169x2y/)**

```
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```